# Gitlab CI - ERROR: Preparation failed: adding cache volume: set volume permissions: running permission container

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a Gitlab-Runner (version: 15.5.1) in a VM (Ubuntu  20.04.5 lts). The docker version is 22.06.0-beta.0. I'm trying to run a pipeline which use node:latest image but The following error messages occur when I run the pipeline.
[image]
The configuration (config.toml) is :

```
    [[runners]]
      name = "runner-web"
      url = "my url here"
      id = 8
      token = "Q_9sEzj9y2sPPJTLnGpL"
      token_obtained_at = 2022-12-01T14:09:45Z
      token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
      executor = "docker"
      [runners.custom_build_dir]
      [runners.cache]
        [runners.cache.s3]
        [runners.cache.gcs]
        [runners.cache.azure]
      [runners.docker]
        tls_verify = false
        image = "docker:latest"
        privileged = true
        disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
        oom_kill_disable = false
        disable_cache = false
        volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock","/cache"]
        shm_size = 0
```

Could it be  disk space issues ?
This is the disk space in the VM.
[image]